# Else if Logic Flow

Tags: java

I've been programming under the assumption that `if ... else if` statements were short circuited. That is, if a condition fulfills the `if` statement, then the `else if` statement is not visited. Recent behavior in a program of mine is throwing that into question. Here's the code, which iterates over an array and checks if each value in the array matches its index +1:

```
        int[] boardCopy = this.getBoard();
        int length = boardCopy.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            //blank space must be in last position
            if (boardCopy[i] == 0 && i != length -1) return false;
            //out of order if value does not match index + 1 (zero indexed)
            else if (boardCopy[i] != i +1) {
                System.out.println("Out of order: " + boardCopy[i] + ", " + (i+1));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Here is the array I'm testing it on:

```
int[] blocks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0};
```

When I create a board that is in order (values match indices + 1 AND the 0 is in the last position), it returns `false`. My print statement reveals that the `else if` statement is checking the 0 position even though the `if` statement logic is fulfilled.

Is my entire conception of the `if/elseif` logic flow incorrect? Is my codeview about to be shattered?

Comment: How can you iterate over a 2D array with a single index? Does Java allow that?

Comment: OOOOPS sorry guys, I convert the 2D array into a 1D array, will edit...

Comment: well both your conditions return false. Are you sure your code isn't always entering the else if block?

edit: A return statement means you exit the method so I'm guessing your (&& i != length -1) is not returning what you want it to return.

Comment: Your conception of if/else is right; your code is definitely wrong.  We can't see enough of your code to figure out what is wrong, though.

Comment: Added more code for context and showed the 1D array I'm using without the code... good to know that my if/else logic wasn't wrong all these years.

Comment: Could you add the output that code produces?

Comment: So what happens if neither statement is true?

Comment: how is length defined? in your first condition BOTH conditions must be true for the else to not get visited

Comment: Oh my god. I posted code for the wrong segment when I edited... Wow.... one more edit coming.

Comment: since boardCopy is an array, use getLength() instead of length

Comment: I can't really tell what your question is, but if an `if` condition is true, no other `else` statements will execute. If an `if` condition isn't true, other conditions will be checked. Not much else to say about it.

Comment: Code updated. Why is getLength() superior to length for arrays? int length is the length of the array.

Comment: the code returns false for the ordered array I posted in the code. The "out of order" object is the 0, despite the if condition about 0s at the beginning. Edit: one last edit to reflect the 1D array.... sorry for such a messy question.

Comment: In your `else` statement, you return `False` as well. Are you sure `False` get returned in the `if` statement???

Comment: @Joetjah Yes. I only return true if I make it through the entire loop. The first if statement is meant to handle the case of 0, which doesn't fall neatly into the else if statement's logic. Maybe 2 if statements would be better from a code sanity standpoint? Or a single compound if statement?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne I don't understand that; since when have arrays had a `getLength()` method? They *should* have a `getLength()` method, but that's different than having one.

Comment: @user1427661 Please use `@` replies, otherwise it's (a) difficult to follow, and (b) users may not be notified you've talked to them.

Comment: @user1427661 If I run this code it yields `Out of order: 0, 9`, which is valid if-else logic. At `i == 8` the first condition evaluates to `false`, because `8 != 9 - 1` is false. Then the else clause is checked and since `board[8] != 9`, you get out-of-order.

Comment: @DaveNewton http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @JeffHawthorne That is not a method on an array, that is a static method in `Array`. In other words, `Array.getLength(anArray)`. That is very different, and it's not clear why you advocate that over `anArray.length`. (If that's what you're advocating, because your comment is ambiguously worded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed:
If I run this code it yields `Out of order: 0, 9`, which is valid if-else logic.

At `i == 8` the first condition evaluates to false, because `8 != 9 - 1` is false.

Then the else clause is checked and since `board[8] != 9`, you get "Out of order".

I think you want

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //blank space must be in last position
        if (boardCopy[i] == 0) {
            if (i != length -1) {
                return false;
            }
            continue;   // can be in an else block or omitted
        }
        //out of order if value does not match index + 1 (zero indexed)
        else if (boardCopy[i] != i +1) {
            System.out.println("Out of order: " + boardCopy[i] + ", " + (i+1));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Jeez, you had this sent like 2 seconds before I did... GG!

Comment: You're missing a `}` between `continue` and `else`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that rather than discuss this ad infinitum in the comments section you add a `println` at the following points...

- The very first line in the `for` loop (before your first if)
- Before the first `return false` - you will obviously need to delimit this block with `{}`

This print should show the value of `i`, `boardCopy[i]`, `length`

Also, include a final `else` block which has a `println` showing the same.

Identify each `println` so you know which line is printing (eg prefix with `1:` `2:` etc)

I'm pretty sure output will be enlightening :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (boardCopy[i] == 0 && i != length -1) return false;
    //out of order if value does not match index + 1 (zero indexed)
    else if (boardCopy[i] != i +1) {
        System.out.println("Out of order: " + boardCopy[i] + ", " + (i+1));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You run your above code on:

```
int[] blocks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0};
```

This means `length = 9`.

Now, when you go through the numbers, your first if-statement will not block untill you hit 0. The first condition of your if-statement is `True`. The second is: `i != length -1`, or better said: `i != 8`. Your `i` has its value set to 8 the moment the loop has arrived on your 0. Remember, in the first loop, i=0. Therefore, your if statement will always be true with your set of `blocks`.